# Slow response of onTouchListener in few line code

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I have not a found a relevant answer to my problem. I have the following `onTouchListener`:

```
findViewById(R.id.imageView).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            text.setText("" + count);
            count++;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

There is nothing else on the activity, but when I click on the ImageView I can see, that text will not change immediately. It changes after some delay (100ms). When I tap fast, number isn't increasing by 1, but sometimes by 3 or 4. How can I get a faster response?

Comment: i think it's related to the listener, being of type `OnTouch`, just a wild guess, maybe because it has more events , DOWN, UP, DRAG, ... so can you try to use `OnClickListener` i.e `...setOnClickListener(new onClic...() `? does it make a difference ? plz try and update us

Comment: thank you for response. I try onClickListener and same result. I also notice, that when i am tapping really fast and stop, its still increasing that value for another second. Its seems to be saved in some buffer. I am using Samsung A5 2017 for testing.

Comment: yes, i think events are queued because they are all executed on the main thread (UI Thread) then they are executed sequentially one by one, the thing is, ur code is really simple, unless the phone is running something else in the background that causes this lag? or it could be completely normal, i mean you could be hitting the top limit of the clicks speed? may be someone else can help with this

Comment: Its wierd. My phone is 1 week old and almost with no apps. I set to change text on "HOLD" event and when i am holding finger down see text to quickly change 1->2->3 and lag (100-200ms) and again increasing by few numbers and again lag. Lags are not regular, its almost random.

Comment: FYI: I created blank activity, changed android:theme to ".NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" and MainActivity changed to "...extends Activity".
Thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found root cause. Its because ImageView have defined in XML

> android:src="@drawable/a"

And "a" is PNG image (20,9KB...1579x1945) as background. When i remove this line in XML, its a much faster.

Solution will be better preparing image or something like that.